# Strange sound from motherboard

Tags: motherboard, bios, intel-pentium

I have a MSI 7222 ver 1.1 motherboard, a Intel Pentium 4 3.0 GHz/1M/800/04A processor and 2x1 GB of DDR2 RAM. When I boot the computer, the motherboard makes a "siren sound" (like low pitch and higher pitch) without stopping until the config stops by itself. What could be the source of the problem?

Edit : Should it be a problem of cpu compatibility?

Comment: What do you mean by 'without stopping until the config stops by itself'?

Comment: I could not find any siren like descriptions in [the manual](http://www.manualslib.com/download/360304/Msi-Ms-7222.html), but it does remind me of an overheating alert. Can you check if the CPU fan is working and/or what the CPU temperatures are in the BIOS, (http://i.stack.imgur.com/KPO9Q.png)

Comment: The computer stops before I could access the bios.. it make also the bip stops

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of moving devices that could make this type of noise; fans and hard drives. Disks usually make intermittent noises, fans constant.  You can eliminate the disk by removing it and try booting from a USB. To pinpoint the noise from multiple fans, use a small piece of rubber tubing as an improvised stethoscope. With one end in your ear and poking around with the other, its amazing how you can directly pinpoint the noise source.

I had a similar sounding random noise that turned out to be a defective hard drive. The noise only happened when certain parts of the disk were being read and at limited temperatures.

Comment: I've done that and the beep sound come from my motherboard speaker (I had the good idea to put the rubber on it and there were no more sound...) After that I removed HDD and fans (except cpu one) and it's still beeping...

Comment: That's good info that you should add to your question. I'll delete my response once you do.

Answer (score 0):

what you have is a BIOS issue, check if the manual had some info about the POST signals or check online [this page](http://forum-en.msi.com/faq/article/bios-beep-codes), it can help you, but first you need to know what's your bios brand (sometimes it say it on screen, otherwise you need to access the bios) so you can know for sure what's going on